# Access docker wordpress data over network

Tags: wordpress, docker

I have created wordpress network using docker compose. Here is the setup I used:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:
```

Site is up and running on localhost. When trying to connect to this site from another computer on network I can see all the static parts of website but when I try open post that is saved in db I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

What do I need to change in order for other computers access data from db?
Thanks